# Trying to break up list items dynamically

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to fill an unordered vertical list that continues on the next line every time the list reaches the length limit. But instead of simply displaying the next list item on the next line I want the list item to break and continue like this:

[image]

I don't want to do this with columns, rather that it breaks dynamically.

Comment: what code you have now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this to make the list horizontal and to create your own custom list-style-type?

Code:

```html
<style>

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 450px;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}

li:before {
    content: "\2022";
    margin-right: 2px;
}

</style>

<ul>
    <li>Lorom Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorom Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorom Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorom Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorom Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorom Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorom Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorom Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about giving your `<ul>` a set max-width, then give your `<li>` `display: inline;` so they aren't block elements anymore and wrap like you want. However list-style-type will not work on the li's anymore because they are inline elements. You can still get your red bullet points working with background images, looks like you might be already doing this.

```css
ul {
  max-width: 220px;
  list-style-type: disc;
  
}

ul li {
 display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>Hey there this is a pretty long sentence</li>
 <li>Hey there this is a pretty long sentence</li>
 <li>Hey there this is a pretty long sentence</li>
 <li>Hey there this is a pretty long sentence</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use css to change the way of items are listed.

Ex:

```css
ul {
    width: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
}
li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
      <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 1 item 2</li>
        <li>item 1 item 2 item 3</li>
        <li>item n</li>
      </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `li` are not breaking/wrapping mid-sentence.